# Efficient drawing of video frames in python GUI

Tags: python, numpy, user-interface, drawing

Currently I am working on a project where I have some hardware including a camera. The hardware will stream the camera frames over the network to my python program. This is working already, basically I have a numpy array available with the raw pixel data of the image in BGR Format.

**I want to have a GUI that will rapidly redraw incoming video frames and maybe later also include some functional buttons.**

I have already been looking around at some solutions like using pygame library and converting my numpy array to a pygame surface, or using tkinter and loading the numpy array as image and drawing that. However with pygame creating buttons might be harder and with tkinter the performance might not be enough.

My main concern is that the video will be smooth with at least 15fps. The frames are 640x480 Pixels so I am asking for a very efficient solution. I am also open for suggestions in other directions, right now the main reason for using python is that I also want to perfom some Machine Learning on the video frames, but if there are other easy solutions like using another language to display the GUI and video and doing the Machine Learning part by calling python from there, it would also be fine.

Comment: Pygame has no built-in gui functionality but I would try it. You could use `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` and `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` for the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to try it with moderngl / moderngl_window and the results seem to be performant enough. Monderngl_window had an interesting example code (a video player), that was very similar to what I wanted to achieve: https://github.com/moderngl/moderngl-window/blob/master/examples/video.py

My code is using the same concept as in above example, so I just write the bytes of the numpy array to the texture and draw it. To make the rendering loop and the network receiving of the frames independent, they each have their own thread. To share the numpy array between the threads, I use an underlying SharedMemory buffer.

Results are

- Rendering with 60 fps
- Updating Frames with 30 fps (as much as the camera allows)